# how to draw into a PaintDC and MemoryDC in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, wxpython, gdi

I'm looking for a pice of code, how to use a wx.PaintDC() and wx.MemoryDC in parallel.
My wxPython is in version 2.8.12 and I do not get it work to draw to a wx.PaintDC() into a wx.Window, while
also having a thread running, that draws to a wx.MemoryDC into a bitmap.

Like this:

```
def onPaint(self, evt):
  self.dc=wx.PaintDC(self)
  imgbuf, (sx, sy), self.refresh_needed=self.osm.getBitmap()
  self.dc.DrawBitmap(imgbuf, sx, sy)

as_thread()
  w, h=self.__getBitmapSize()
  self.bmpbuf=wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(w, h, 204, 204, 204, 1)
  self.mdc=wx.MemoryDC()
  self.mdc.SelectObject(self.bmpbuf)
  [.....]
  y=0
  for yi in imgs:
    x=0
    for tn, (status, xi) in yi:
      if status!=self.status["GOOD"]:
        xi=wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(256, 256, red=255, alpha=1)
        if status!=self.status["INVALID"]:
          needs_refresh=True
      self.mdc.DrawBitmap(xi, x, y)
      x+=self.ts
    y+=self.ts
```

*imgbuf* and *self.bmpbuf* are **not** the same object.

*self.bmpbuf* is copied with this:

```
w, h=self.__getBitmapSize()
buf=numpy.empty((w, h, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)
self.bmpbuf.CopyToBuffer(buf)
self.v[handle].bmpbuf=wx.BitmapFromBuffer(w, h, buf)
```

But always getting errors like:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: xcb_io.c:165: dequeue_pending_request: Zusicherung »!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq« nicht erfüllt.
```

**EDIT:**
here is a fully *working* demonstrator-script, that shows the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import random
import time
import threading

class TestWin(wx.Window):
  def __init__(self, parent, title, size):
    wx.Window.__init__(self, parent)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer)
    t=threading.Thread(target=self.asThread, name="draw")
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    self.timer=wx.Timer(self)
    self.timer.Start(100)

  def onPaint(self, evt):
    dc=wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("BLACK"))
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("BLUE"))
    w, h=self.GetSize()
    dc.DrawCirclePoint((random.randint(0, w), random.randint(0, h)), 5)

  def onTimer(self, evt):
    self.Refresh()

  def asThread(self):
    w, h=self.GetSize()
    bmpbuf=wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(w, h, 204, 204, 204, 1)
    mdc=wx.MemoryDC()
    mdc.SelectObject(bmpbuf)
    time.sleep(1)
    mdc.SetPen(wx.Pen("BLACK"))
    mdc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("RED"))
    print "now writing to MemoryDC"
    while True:
      #time.sleep(0.0001)
      mdc.DrawCirclePoint((random.randint(0, w), random.randint(0, h)), 5)
      wx.Yield()

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, title, size):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title)
    win=TestWin(self, title, size)

if __name__=="__main__":
  app=wx.App(False)
  frame=TestFrame(None, "Test", size=(200, 200))
  frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT2:** why I want to build a bitmap in a thread:
I have a class providing a bitmap (showing OpenStreetMap-tiles) for a given window-size, zoom-level and lat/lon-coordinate.
The class also draws GPS-tracks and point-lists onto the map/bitmap.
Because the dimensions of the bitmap are higher than the window-dimensions, I can move the bitmap under the window without building a new bitmap.
To move the bitmap, dc.DrawBitmap(imgbuf, sx, sy) is called with slightly changed values for (sx, sy). This takes 0.1ms per new clipping. Building a new bitmap takes up to 150ms.
When *scrolling* from one to another position, it scrolls very smooth until a new bitmap is needed.
If it would be possible to prepare the new bitmap, while scrolling over the *old* bitmap, a continuously smooth scrolling over a long distance should be possible.

Comment: seems to be working on  wxpython 4.0.0a1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not (and in most cases, can not) manipulate UI objects from anything other than the main UI thread. That includes DCs and bitmaps. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There is likely some other way to do it.

Comment: see my EDIT2....an idea for "some other way" how to scroll smoothly over a dynamically created sequence of bitmaps is highly welcome.

Comment: If you're using numpy arrays for fetching and building the image data then that part can be done on a worker thread. Converting to a bitmap for display needs to happen on the GUI thread. One approach I would try would be to have some number of smaller bitmaps instead of one big one, and use a cache to keep some N number of most recently used bitmaps in memory.  Then when scrolling towards one edge happens you can use the thread to fetch the data and then convert to bitmaps in an EVT_IDLE event or similar and then add them to the cache so they are waiting for EVT_PAINT when it needs them.

Comment: Great idea....and I had this idea too....running my class with numpy and Pillow - instead of wx. It should be possible to draw the map and point-lists this way also. But for the tracks, I need to draw lines onto the bitmap. And doing this pixel per pixel in Python will be much too slow (I guess).

Comment: I now have rewritten my class to do all the drawing with pillow. Only one call to a wx-Function is still needed: wx.BitmapFromBuffer(w, h, self.v[handle].bmpbuf.tostring()).