# Error in testing wxpython on Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: python, wxpython

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx, wx.media
import sqlite3
import os
import time

class MainFream(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.leftPanel = wx.Panel(self, size=(0,0), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.media = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self,
                                        szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER,
                                        #szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_DIRECTSHOW,
                                        #szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10,
                                        size=(0,0),
                                        style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        image = wx.Image('1.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.background = wx.StaticBitmap(self.leftPanel, -1, image, (0,0))

        self.hBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.hBoxSizer.Add(self.leftPanel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.hBoxSizer.Add(self.media, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.hBoxSizer)

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        self.mediaCounter = 0
        self.folderSerach = [f for f in os.listdir('./') if f.endswith(('.mpg', '.jpg', '.mp4', '.avi'))]
        self.media.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.mediaPlay, self.media)
        self.media.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.mediaLoop, self.media)
        self.media.Load(self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter])

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.autoRefresh, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(100000)

        self.count = 0

        self.Text()
        self.LoadText()
        self.FontSizeColor()
        self.TextSizer()

    def autoRefresh(self, event):
        self.LoadText()
        self.FontSizeColor()

    def mediaPlay(self, event):
        if self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter].endswith('jpg'):
            self.media.Play()
            time.sleep(7)
        else:
            self.media.Play()

    def mediaLoop(self, evnet):
        self.media.Stop()
        self.mediaCounter += 1
        self.count += 1
        if self.mediaCounter > len(self.folderSerach) -1: self.mediaCounter = 0
        self.media.Load(self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter])
        self.folderSerach = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(('.mpg', '.jpg', '.mp4', '.avi'))]
        print(self.count, self.folderSerach)

    def Text(self):
        self.title = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, label='TEST1', style=wx.EXPAND)
        self.staticText1_1 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, label="TEST2", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_2 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, label="TEST3", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_3 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, label="TEST4", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_4 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, label="TEST5", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_5 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, label="TEST6", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_6 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, label="TEST7", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.staticText2_1 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_2 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_3 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_4 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_5 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_6 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.staticText3_1 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText3_2 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText3_3 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText3_4 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText3_5 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText3_6 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.staticText4_1 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText4_2 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText4_3 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText4_4 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText4_5 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText4_6 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.staticText5_1 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText5_2 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText5_3 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText5_4 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText5_5 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText5_6 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)       

    def LoadText(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM CLINIC1")
        for data1 in self.cursor.fetchall(): pass
        self.staticText2_1.SetLabel(data1[1])
        self.staticText2_2.SetLabel(data1[2])
        self.staticText2_3.SetLabel(data1[3])
        self.staticText2_4.SetLabel(data1[4])
        self.staticText2_5.SetLabel(data1[5])
        self.staticText2_6.SetLabel(data1[6])

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM CLINIC2")
        for data2 in self.cursor.fetchall(): pass
        self.staticText3_1.SetLabel(data2[1])
        self.staticText3_2.SetLabel(data2[2])
        self.staticText3_3.SetLabel(data2[3])
        self.staticText3_4.SetLabel(data2[4])
        self.staticText3_5.SetLabel(data2[5])
        self.staticText3_6.SetLabel(data2[6])

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM CLINIC3")
        for data3 in self.cursor.fetchall(): pass
        self.staticText4_1.SetLabel(data3[1])
        self.staticText4_2.SetLabel(data3[2])
        self.staticText4_3.SetLabel(data3[3])
        self.staticText4_4.SetLabel(data3[4])
        self.staticText4_5.SetLabel(data3[5])
        self.staticText4_6.SetLabel(data3[6])

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM CLINIC4")
        for data4 in self.cursor.fetchall(): pass
        self.staticText5_1.SetLabel(data4[1])
        self.staticText5_2.SetLabel(data4[2])
        self.staticText5_3.SetLabel(data4[3])
        self.staticText5_4.SetLabel(data4[4])
        self.staticText5_5.SetLabel(data4[5])
        self.staticText5_6.SetLabel(data4[6])

    def FontSizeColor(self):
        self.title_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText1_1_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText1_2_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText1_3_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText1_4_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText1_5_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText1_6_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)

        self.staticText2_1_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText2_2_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText2_3_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText2_4_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText2_5_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText2_6_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)

        self.staticText3_1_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText3_2_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText3_3_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText3_4_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText3_5_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText3_6_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)

        self.staticText4_1_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText4_2_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText4_3_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText4_4_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText4_5_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText4_6_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)

        self.staticText5_1_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText5_2_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText5_3_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText5_4_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText5_5_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.staticText5_6_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)

        self.staticText2_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText2_2.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText2_3.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        for color1 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC1'):
            if color1[4] == 'yes':
                self.staticText2_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color1[4] == 'no':
                self.staticText2_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color1 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC1'):
            if color1[5] == 'yes':
                self.staticText2_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color1[5] == 'no':
                self.staticText2_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color1 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC1'):
            if color1[6] == 'yes':
                self.staticText2_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color1[6] == 'no':
                self.staticText2_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))

        self.staticText3_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText3_2.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText3_3.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        for color2 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC2'):
            if color2[4] == 'yes':
                self.staticText3_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color2[4] == 'no':
                self.staticText3_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color2 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC2'):
            if color2[5] == 'yes':
                self.staticText3_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color2[5] == 'no':
                self.staticText3_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color2 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC2'):
            if color2[6] == 'yes':
                self.staticText3_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color2[6] == 'no':
                self.staticText3_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))

        self.staticText4_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText4_2.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText4_3.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        for color3 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC3'):
            if color3[4] == 'yes':
                self.staticText4_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color3[4] == 'no':
                self.staticText4_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color3 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC3'):
            if color3[5] == 'yes':
                self.staticText4_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color3[5] == 'no':
                self.staticText4_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color3 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC3'):
            if color3[6] == 'yes':
                self.staticText4_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color3[6] == 'no':
                self.staticText4_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))

        self.staticText5_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText5_2.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        self.staticText5_3.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 1, 2))
        for color4 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC4'):
            if color4[4] == 'yes':
                self.staticText5_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color4[4] == 'no':
                self.staticText5_4.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color4 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC4'):
            if color4[5] == 'yes':
                self.staticText5_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color4[5] == 'no':
                self.staticText5_5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))
        for color4 in self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM CLINIC4'):
            if color4[6] == 'yes':
                self.staticText5_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 255, 2))
            elif color4[6] == 'no':
                self.staticText5_6.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(204, 1, 2))

        self.title.SetFont(self.title_Font)
        self.staticText1_1.SetFont(self.staticText1_1_Font)
        self.staticText1_2.SetFont(self.staticText1_2_Font)
        self.staticText1_3.SetFont(self.staticText1_3_Font)
        self.staticText1_4.SetFont(self.staticText1_4_Font)
        self.staticText1_5.SetFont(self.staticText1_5_Font)
        self.staticText1_6.SetFont(self.staticText1_6_Font)

        self.staticText2_1.SetFont(self.staticText2_1_Font)
        self.staticText2_2.SetFont(self.staticText2_2_Font)
        self.staticText2_3.SetFont(self.staticText2_3_Font)
        self.staticText2_4.SetFont(self.staticText2_4_Font)
        self.staticText2_5.SetFont(self.staticText2_5_Font)
        self.staticText2_6.SetFont(self.staticText2_6_Font)

        self.staticText3_1.SetFont(self.staticText3_1_Font)
        self.staticText3_2.SetFont(self.staticText3_2_Font)
        self.staticText3_3.SetFont(self.staticText3_3_Font)
        self.staticText3_4.SetFont(self.staticText3_4_Font)
        self.staticText3_5.SetFont(self.staticText3_5_Font)
        self.staticText3_6.SetFont(self.staticText3_6_Font)

        self.staticText4_1.SetFont(self.staticText4_1_Font)
        self.staticText4_2.SetFont(self.staticText4_2_Font)
        self.staticText4_3.SetFont(self.staticText4_3_Font)
        self.staticText4_4.SetFont(self.staticText4_4_Font)
        self.staticText4_5.SetFont(self.staticText4_5_Font)
        self.staticText4_6.SetFont(self.staticText4_6_Font)

        self.staticText5_1.SetFont(self.staticText5_1_Font)
        self.staticText5_2.SetFont(self.staticText5_2_Font)
        self.staticText5_3.SetFont(self.staticText5_3_Font)
        self.staticText5_4.SetFont(self.staticText5_4_Font)
        self.staticText5_5.SetFont(self.staticText5_5_Font)
        self.staticText5_6.SetFont(self.staticText5_6_Font)     

    def TextSizer(self):
        self.gridSizer = wx.GridSizer(17, 6, 0, 5)
        self.textSizers = (
            self.staticText1_1, self.staticText1_2, self.staticText1_3,
            self.staticText1_4, self.staticText1_5, self.staticText1_6,
            self.staticText2_1, self.staticText2_2, self.staticText2_3,
            self.staticText2_4, self.staticText2_5, self.staticText2_6,
            self.staticText3_1, self.staticText3_2, self.staticText3_3,
            self.staticText3_4, self.staticText3_5, self.staticText3_6,
            self.staticText4_1, self.staticText4_2, self.staticText4_3,
            self.staticText4_4, self.staticText4_5, self.staticText4_6,
            self.staticText5_1, self.staticText5_2, self.staticText5_3,
            self.staticText5_4, self.staticText5_5, self.staticText5_6,          
        )
        for textSizer in self.textSizers:
            self.gridSizer.Add(textSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 1)
        self.vttextSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vttextSizer.Add(self.title, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP, 1)
        self.vttextSizer.Add(self.gridSizer, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 1)
        self.leftPanel.SetSizer(self.vttextSizer)
"""
class TransparentText(wx.StaticText):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='', pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name=''):
        wx.StaticText.__init__(self, parent, id, label, pos, size, style, name)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, lambda event: None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)

    def on_paint(self, event):
        bdc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc = wx.GCDC(bdc)

        font_face = self.GetFont()
        font_color = self.GetForegroundColour()

        dc.SetFont(font_face)
        dc.SetTextForeground(font_color)
        dc.DrawText(self.GetLabel(), 0, 0)

    def on_size(self, event):
        self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    fream = MainFream()
    fream.ShowFullScreen(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

On Windows, staticText is not transparent. I want to use Linux.
On Windows, it works without errors other than transparency.

I am trying to run a program made by Python on barebone computer. I am not sure why I get this error while running test with vmware before installing on barebonePC.

```
Ubuntu 16.04 64bit (vmware 12)
[Xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[Xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[Xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
Python3: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `! Xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq 'failed.
Core dumped

Debian 9 64bit (vmware 12)
MyServer2.py: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server: 0.

[Xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[Xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[Xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
Python3: ../../src/xcb_io.c:165: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `! Xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq 'failed.
```

The barebonePC specifications for installing Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 9 x86 are N3000 (1.04GHz) and DDR3L (2G).

The pc spec currently being tested with vmware
I5-4570, ram 8G vmware settings are set to core 2, ram 2g and tested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to draw into a PaintDC and MemoryDC in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524053/how-to-draw-into-a-paintdc-and-memorydc-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/xcb-Unknown-request-in-queue-while-dequeuing-td5480662.html

> All UI actions for a given window must be done by the thread that created the window.  This is because all of the window messages get routed to the creating thread, and there is no protective interlocking.